# unable to hide dev folder coming to sftp (cygwin)

Tags: cygwin, sftp, windows-server-2012-r2

I am working on an sftp using cygwin  in windows 2012 R2

In /etc/fstab  added below two config. The cygdrive is getting hide. But i am able to see dev folder.

```
/dev /null none bind
none / cygdrive user 0 0
```

Is it possible to hide that? What i am missing in order to achieve that.

Comment: What FTP server are you using ?

Comment: I am using SFTP using sshd. Subsystem system i am using it is internal-sftp. Because i dont want anyone to ssh.

Comment: Have you tried to chroot the user https://www.howtoforge.com/restricting-users-to-sftp-plus-setting-up-chrooted-ssh-sftp-debian-squeeze instead of trying hiding directories ?

Comment: I am doing chroot. So when we do that apart from sftp folder you will also have dev folder. I dont want this folder in my sftp location. Because in dev folder you will only have device file . And when someone loging to sftp. There is no mean of showing it. Please let me know ,you got this issue anytime.

Comment: See https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config at `ChrootDirectory` a `dev` directory is required.